How to logout or signout of the model ui?
I'm having a bit of a headache with the MLflow UI. So, I logged into the MLflow tracking website earlier, and now I can't seem to properly log out. It's driving me nuts!
I've tried all sorts of things. First, I just closed the browser thinking that would do the trick. Nope, still remembered me when I opened it back up. Then I thought, "Okay, maybe a hard reload will sort this out." But no dice there either.

which browser and which mlflow server version? I tested with chrome and mlflow 2.12.1 an closing the browser successfully logged me out.
